# Why Doctrine/Symfony2 doesn't see my relations

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have two entities with relation between them defined like this:

```
    <many-to-one
            field="customer"
            target-entity="ITME\UserBundle\Entity\User" inversed-by="orders">
        <join-column name="customer_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
    </many-to-one>



/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\ITME\OrderBundle\Entity\CustomerOrder", 
    mappedBy="customer")
 */
protected $orders;
```

When I add some orders and set the user and then try to get to those orders from User the array collection of orders is empty. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think that you can't combine Annotation and XML mappings in one namespace. Try to avoid this. I think that can help.

Comment: If you look closely he is actually relating entities from two different bundles.  So different mapping formats is acceptable.  I'm guessing his UserBundle is actually extended from FOSUserBundle hence the xml.

Comment: Check the database tables to see if the foreign id's are being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the doc explains:

```
<many-to-one
        field="category"
        target-entity="Category"
        inversed-by="products"
        join-column="category">

        <join-column name="category_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
</many-to-one>
```

Hope it will help you.